# Cricket player involved in any other sports

Tags: cricket

I just wondering. Is any cricket player involved in any other sports for his country rather than cricket. While they still playing international cricket. I knew [Jonty Rhodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonty_Rhodes) played hockey for South Africa but I am not sure he played international level.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad: list-type questions don't work well on Stack Exchange.

Comment: [Ellyse Perry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellyse_Perry) . represented Australia in Football and Cricket

Answer (score 1):

There are number of players.

The first one came to my mind is [AB de Villiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AB_de_Villiers).

Some of his achievements are listed below ([Reference](http://www.mid-day.com/articles/ab-de-villiers---a-hockey-football-rugby-tennis-and-badminton-champ/15286163)).

- He was shortlisted for South Africa's junior national hockey team.
- He made it to the shortlist of South Africa's junior national football team.
- He was captain of South Africa's junior national rugby team.
- He holds six South African school swimming records.
- He holds the record in the 100m dash in South Africa's junior athletics.
- He was a member of South Africa's junior Davis Cup tennis team.
- He was South Africa's U-19 national badminton champion.
- Has a golf handicap of scratch or zero, which means he is a player whose average score for a round of golf is par or better.

Here is a [list](http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/508258.html) of some Cricketers who excelled at other sports, you can [google](https://www.google.com/#q=cricketers+in+other+sports) for more results. :)

Comment: But did he do that *while* playing international cricket or before that?

Comment: I believe all these achievements are before his first International Cricket match(for senior team) , I don't have exact timeline of his early sports life.